# In Jetpack Compose how do I fill the height of a view when its sibling is already using weight?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Column` with a green square and another `Column` that contains a `Text` and a `Button` (screenshot 1). The green square has fixed height of 500, but in practice I do not know this height. It might be different in certain scenarios. I have these requirements:

- Whenever there is too much text in the bottom `Column`, I want the green square to shrink when there is no more room left in the bottom `Column`, which is achieved by putting `Modifier.weight(1F, false)` on the green square.
- If there is enough room, I want to have as much space as possible space between the `Text` and the `Button`, while still showing the full height of the green square. So I put a `Spacer` between the `Text` and the `Button` with `.weight(1F)`. However, this results in screenshot 2 where it takes over the whole height of the screen and the green square isn't visible anymore.

How do I make the bottom `Column` fill up the rest of the available space while the green square has `.weight(1F, false)`? I can't give it a weight directly because that will divide the total weight between the green square and the bottom `Column`. I also cannot apply `.fillMaxHeight()` since that will have the same effect as the `Spacer`. Is this even possible in Compose? I also don't think I can use `BoxWithConstraints` since that requires knowing the size of the green square beforehand. And I already mentioned that it is dynamic in practice.

Example code:

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        GreenSquare(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1F, false)
        )

        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text",
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 80.dp)
            )

            // The issue:
            // Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1F))

            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GreenSquare(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(500.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Green)
    )
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just Remove ```Weight(1F)``` from ```Box``` Because you have already given fixed height so it will work as you want

Comment: @ChiragThummar If I do that, the green square won't shrink in size if the text in the bottom Column increases and needs more space. So that is not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not what you asked, but as an alternative solution you can use a custom layout.

**Layout**

```
@Composable
fun CustomLayout(
    shrinkableTop: @Composable () -> Unit,
    expandingMid: @Composable () -> Unit,
    fixedFooter: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Layout(
        contents = listOf(shrinkableTop, expandingMid, fixedFooter),
        modifier = modifier,
    ) { (topMeasurables, midMeasurables, footerMeasurables), constraints ->
        val layoutWidth = constraints.maxWidth
        val layoutHeight = constraints.maxHeight
        val footerPlaceable = footerMeasurables.first().measure(constraints)
        val midHeightAvailable = (layoutHeight - footerPlaceable.height).coerceAtLeast(0)
        val midPlaceable = midMeasurables.first().measure(
            constraints.copy(maxHeight = midHeightAvailable)
        )
        val topHeightAvailable = (layoutHeight - footerPlaceable.height - midPlaceable.height)
            .coerceAtLeast(0)
        val topPlaceable = topMeasurables.first().measure(
            constraints.copy(maxHeight = topHeightAvailable)
        )
        layout(layoutWidth, layoutHeight) {
            topPlaceable.place(0, 0)
            midPlaceable.place(
                x = (layoutWidth - midPlaceable.width) / 2,
                y = topPlaceable.height
            )
            footerPlaceable.place(
                x = (layoutWidth - footerPlaceable.width) / 2,
                y = constraints.maxHeight - footerPlaceable.height
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
    val text = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>() }
    CustomLayout(
        shrinkableTop = {
            GreenSquare()
        },
        expandingMid = {
            Text(
                text = text.joinToString(separator = "\n"),
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 80.dp)
            )
        },
        fixedFooter = {
            Row {
                Button(onClick = { repeat(3) { text.add("Line of text") } }) {
                    Text(text = "ADD")
                }
                Button(onClick = { repeat(3) { text.removeLastOrNull() } }) {
                    Text(text = "REMOVE")
                }
            }
        },
    )
```

[image: screen capture]